# UIToolbar and UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitoolbar

I am making a music application where I have the list of music populated in a uitableview and the player is a uitoolbar, which is just after the tableview. I am stuck on how to make the uitoolbar to be listening to the table cell selected, once the row is selected, then uitoolbar should be able to play the music from the selected row. If I know how to make the two cooperate, then I can continue with the rest to make the music play. Let's say I get the text of the selected row. I will really appreciate.

Comment: Your view controller, or some other object should communicate between these objects.  The table view should tell the object when the cell is selected.  Upon receiving the message, this object should then tell the player to switch songs.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you want to sent a message to the toolbar ?

Can you not just call a method on the toolbar e.g. `[YOURTOOLBAR playMusicFileAtPath:MUSICFILEPATH]` ?

Like this:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *filePath = [DATASOURCE FILEPATH];

    [YOURTOOLBAR PLAYFILEATPATH:filePath];

}
```

Comment: Yes I would like to send a message to a toolbar.The design of my music list is a viewcontroller, which i inserted a tableview, then added a toolbar at the bottom. So all these are in one place.So like you suggested I do [YOURTOOLBAR PLAYFILEATPATH:filePath].Am wondering where to place PLAYFILEATPATH and have it being called by my toolbar, which is not a class as I just dragged it to viewcontroller scene. :(

Comment: Well  if its on the same VC then just play the music in cellForRow and update the toolbar UI to reflect the title etc ... ?